# Remove the windows form controls on exit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, visual-studio-2010

I'm adding the form controls on loading the form manually:

```
Me.FieldI = New TextBox()
Me.FieldI.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 10)
Me.FieldI.Name = "FieldI"
Me.FieldI.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(40, 20)
Me.FieldI.TabIndex = 5
Me.Conversion.Controls.Add(Me.FieldI)
[..]
```

When I close the form window and reopen it, the control is still there (with the old `.Text` content , because its an textbox in this case).

I would like to remove the controls that have been created while form loading on the form close event, to prevent doubling the elements on my form.

How can I achieve this?

## edit

Form closing code looks following (just showing up the main form back):

```
Private Sub Form1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Main.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: It will be interesting to know how do you close the form and how do you reopen the form. This behavior should not happen if you really destroy the form and open a new instance of it

Comment: I have edited my post. There is nothing added except the `Main.Show()` to show the main form back.

Comment: When I add `Me.Conversion.Controls.Remove(Me.FieldI)` on the form close event, it does work properly... but do I really need to remove that amount of form elements manually? (about `20` elements)

Comment: You are add the control on Form.Load or Form.Activated ??

Comment: @MandeepSingh I'm adding the control on the `Form.Load` event.

Comment: And how about you reopen it?

Comment: `Steve` reopen the whole application or just the current form with the controls? When I reopen the whole application and open my subform, its working fine for the first time, but when I close the subform (`Form1`) and reopen it, then elements doubling in my subforum.

Comment: What is the desired output here? Are you hiding the main form when the subform is opened, or is it still visible? Do you want the user to be able to open mutiple subforms?

Comment: The posted code is not sufficient to repro the problem.  The only thing obvious is that you use some fairly poor practices in picking names and adding event handlers.  You'll need to make a small repro project that exhibits this problem and post it on a file sharing service if you need somebody else to debug it for you.

Comment: @JackPettinger No, I'm not hiding the main form, while opening the subform. There is just a simple button in the main form, and simple code so when the button is clicked, subform is showing up as an dialog (modal): `subForm.ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the form is not being disposed, so when you open it again the controls are still there from the last time it was opened.

Try the following:

```
Using frm = New subForm()
  frm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

The variable `frm` will be disposed after the using.

**Also...**

You can also provide feedback from a dialog, to check whether the form was successful or not. For example:

```
Dim frm As New subForm()
If frm.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
  'YAY!
Else
  'Something failed
End If
```